# Can watchman send why a file changed?

Tags: watchman

Is watchman capable of posting to the configured command, why it's sending a file to that command?

For example:

1. a file is new to a folder would possibly be a FILE_CREATE flag;
2. a file that is deleted would send to the command the FILE_DELETE flag;
3. a file that's modified would send a FILE_MOD flag etc.
4. Perhaps even when a folder gets deleted (and therefore the files thereunder) would send a FOLDER_DELETE parameter naming the folder, as well as a FILE_DELETE to the files thereunder / FOLDER_DELETE to the folders thereunder

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it can't do that.  The reasons why are pretty fundamental to its design.
The TL;DR is that it is a lot more complicated than you might think for a client to correctly process those individual events and in almost all cases you don't really want them.

Most file watching systems are abstractions that simply translate from the system specific notification information into some common form.  They don't deal, either very well or at all, with the notification queue being overflown and don't provide their clients with a way to reliably respond to that situation.

In addition to this, the filesystem can be subject to many and varied changes in a very short amount of time, and from multiple concurrent threads or processes.  This makes this area extremely prone to [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) issues that are difficult to manage.  For example, creating and writing to a file typically results in a series of notifications about the file and its containing directory.  If the file is removed immediately after this sequence (perhaps it was an intermediate file in a build step), by the time you see the notifications about the file creation there is a good chance that it has already been deleted.

Watchman takes the input stream of notifications and feeds it into its internal model of the filesystem: an ordered list of observed files.  Each time a notification is received watchman treats it as a signal that it should go and look at the file that was reported as changed and then move the entry for that file to the most recent end of the ordered list.

When you ask Watchman for information about the filesystem it is possible or even likely that there may be pending notifications still due from the kernel.  To minimize TOCTOU and ensure that its state is current, watchman generates a [synchronization cookie](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cookies.html) and waits for that notification to be visible before it responds to your query.

The combination of the two things above mean that watchman result data has two important properties:

1. You are guaranteed to have have observed all notifications that happened before your query
2. You receive the most recent information for any given file only once in your query results (the change results are coalesced together)

Let's talk about the overflow case.  If your system is unable to keep up with the rate at which files are changing (eg: you have a big project and are very quickly creating and deleting files and the system is heavily loaded), the OS can't fit all of the pending notifications in the buffer resources allocated to the watches.  When that happens, it blows those buffers and sends an overflow signal.  What that means is that the client of the watching API has missed some number of events and is no longer in synchronization with the state of the filesystem.  If that client is maintains state about the filesystem it is no longer valid.

Watchman addresses this situation by re-examining the watched tree and synthetically marking all of the files as being changed.  This causes the next query from the client to see everything in the tree.  We call this a *fresh instance* result set because it is the same view you'd get when you are querying for the first time.  We set a flag in the result so that the client knows that this has happened and can take appropriate steps to repair its own state.  You can configure this behavior through [query parameters](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/query.html).

In these *fresh instance* result sets, we don't know whether any given file really changed or not (it's possible that it changed in such a way that we can't detect via `lstat`) and even if we can see that its metadata changed, we don't know the cause of that change.

There can be multiple events that contribute to why a given file appears in the results delivered by watchman.  We don't them record them individually because we can't track them with unbounded history; imagine a file that is incrementally being written once every second all day long.  Do we keep 86400 change entries for it per day on hand and deliver those to our clients?  What if there are hundreds of thousands of files like this?  We'd have to truncate that data, and at that point the loss in the data reduces how well you can reason about it.

At the end of all of this, it is very rare for a client to do much more than try to read a file or look at its metadata, and generally speaking, they want to do that only when the file has stopped changing.  For this use case, [watchman-wait](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/watchman-wait.html), [watchman-make](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/watchman-make.html) and [trigger](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/trigger.html) all have the concept of a settle period that causes the change notifications to be delayed in delivery until after the filesystem has stopped changing.

Comment: Wez - first and foremost, thank you for such a detailed answer, I certainly wasn't expecting all that you had written - simple a "nope" would've been expected!  Your explanation really assists me, as I've been using a precedessor to watchman (watcher, by splitbrain) but in continued testing, it appears that I'm losing notifications of files that are even hitting the filesystem (approx 50% in most cases over 100 files) - I'm sure that that project is susceptible of what you've outlined here. I will persevere with watcher in the hope that it'll be able to do what I need it to do. Thank you.